# How do you know what's passed into the callbacks in Facebook's Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, facebook

This is a general question on how to read [Facebook's Javascript API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) documentation. How can I get a complete description on the objects that are passed into my callback functions? Take for example [FB.Login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)'s sparse documentation:

```
Name  |  Type      | Description
-------------------------------------------
cb    |  Function  | The callback function.
```

It does not state what is passed into this callback. I've been using Firebug to inspect the object that is passed back and making guesses on what each property means. My reverse engineering, along with reading of sample code, is not an efficient way to program. I would like to know where I can find the complete Facebook documentation.

Comment: FB's documentation is a joke. If you ever find "the complete Facebook documentation," please, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `FB.Login()` call you asked about, there is this code example:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 });
```

That shows that the callback takes one argument and it's the login response.  The login response appears to be discussed [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) in the doc for `FB.getLoginStatus()`.

```
{
    status: 'connected',
    authResponse: {
        accessToken: '...',
        expiresIn:'...',
        signedRequest:'...',
        userID:'...'
    }
}
```

I would agree that the FB doc doesn't make it clear where to find things like the response object format.

In answer to your general question, it appears you look for a piece of sample code to see how the callback function is declared and then poke around in related methods until you find the doc for the arguments themselves.

Comment: So, basically, I need to randomly search around.